# Update Mutations in GraphQL with Appsync

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm having trouble with update mutations with react-native and amplify.

```
addProfileDetails = async (sub) => {
    let UserDetails = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.updatePeople, {updatePeopleInput: 
         {
            UserID: sub,
            Organization: "Organization"
            Name: "name"
        }
    }));
    console.log(UserDetails);
  };
```

This code doesn't generate any errors, and it's pretty much the same as the code I used to create the record in the first place which works.

but it returns this data and doesn't actually update the record as intended.

```
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "updatePeople": null,
  },
}
```

I tested this query on the appsync query editor:

```
mutation update {
  updatePeople (updatePeopleInput: {
    PersonID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    Gender: "Male"
  })
    {
    PersonID
    Gender
  }
}
```

And it returns the same. Create mutations work, Queries work. I don't understand what is happening here.

Any insights of what I'm doing wrong would be helpful. Also, if you need to the schema or the mutation code, I can provide that.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out.

Turns out the default resolvers created by Appsync just don't work update mutations to my RDS.

I solved this by changing the request resolvers:

```
#set( $updateList = {} )
#foreach( $entry in $ctx.args.updatePeopleInput.keySet() )
  #set( $discard = $updateList.put($entry, "'$ctx.args.updatePeopleInput[$entry]'") )
#end
#set( $update = $updateList.toString().replace("{","").replace("}","") )
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "statements":   [
    $util.toJson("UPDATE People SET Gender='$ctx.args.updatePeopleInput.Gender', Username='$ctx.args.updatePeopleInput.Username' WHERE PersonID='$ctx.args.updatePeopleInput.PersonID'"),
    $util.toJson("SELECT * FROM People WHERE PersonID='$ctx.args.updatePeopleInput.PersonID'")
    ]
}
```

before it was this:

```
#set( $updateList = {} )
#foreach( $entry in $ctx.args.updatePeopleInput.keySet() )
  #set( $discard = $updateList.put($entry, "'$ctx.args.updatePeopleInput[$entry]'") )
#end
#set( $update = $updateList.toString().replace("{","").replace("}","") )
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "statements":   [
    $util.toJson("UPDATE People SET $update WHERE PersonID='$ctx.args.updatePeopleInput.PersonID'"),
    $util.toJson("SELECT * FROM People WHERE PersonID='$ctx.args.updatePeopleInput.PersonID'")
    ]
}
```

Apparently the $update doesn't work and you must explicitly name the variables to be set.

Comment: so, what about if there are multiple column in db, and you want to update only one column value. As off now for update single column value I'm passing all other column values also. Is there any way where the given key value only we can update.